# ajax request all return error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When ever I am doing an ajax request with jquery I always get an error 500 return,

I am posting to the following URL

> http://localhost/domain/index.php/my_profile/interests_music

using this javascript,

```
$("#add").click(function(e){

    //set some process variables, we need to get the forms action, 
    //and any post data it is sending appending isAjax into the params
    //gives us a point in the controller to gracefully check for ajax.
    var action = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
    var formData = $(this).parent('form').serialize()+"&isAjax=1";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: formData
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The params that are being sent are,

> music=Savage Garden&isAjax=1

And the PHP method the ajax is requesting looks like this,

```
public function interests_music()
{
    if($this->input->post('music'))
    {
        $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1'));
        $response = $this->rest->get('mqlread?query={"type":"/music/artist","name":"' . urlencode($this->input->post('music')) . '","id":[]}');
        $data['image'] = 'https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image'.$response->result->id[0].'?mode=fillcrop&maxwidth=80&maxheight=80';
        $data['category'] = 'music';
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $data['name'] = $this->input->post('music', TRUE);

        $this->profile_model->add_interest($data);

        Events::trigger('interests_music');
        Events::trigger('badge_stagediver');

        if($this->input->post('isAjax') == 1)
        {
            echo json_endcode($data);
            $this->_buttons();
        }

        redirect('my_profile/interests');
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, is this a common problem?

Comment: error 500 means server-side error. try looking for typos, and syntax errors. try debugging it while NOT using AJAX. also, try using `json_encode()` instead of manually building JSON responses

Comment: shouldn't you be using .success callback instead of .done

Comment: @AmritpalSingh `.success()` will be deprecated along with `.error()` and `.complete()`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Joseph Right in coming version 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one there's a typo in your PHP which could be what your server is choking on: `echo json_endcode($data);` should be `echo json_encode($data);`. Aside from that there could be other issues with your HTTP server. What server are you using? A good practice is to find the server error log and PHP error log and use `tail -f` or some other method of monitoring the logs which should give you more information when you have 505s.

Comment: +1, also the OP can access their AJAX page via a browser, with errors enabled, to see what the issue is on-screen.

Comment: Yes, very true, not sure why I thought of logs first. sico could probably also set a breakpoint in the `done` handler and introspect the jqXHR object or add success and error handlers to the request.